# Need help porting Java to C# - How to handle anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

I've looked at some of the other answers regarding the java inner anonymous class, but I am looking for something specific to the Xamarin implementation of C#.

I am working to move the openCamera project (http://opencamera.sourceforge.net/) from java to C# in Xamarin.

I am struggling to figure out the best way of handling the anonymous inner class of java.

The Java code snippet (one of many) I am working on is this:

```
    orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            MainActivity.this.onOrientationChanged(orientation);
        }
    };
```

How is that best expressed in Xamarin recognized C# code?

If I use Tangible Software's Java to C# program, it creates a helper class called "OrientationEventListenerAnonymousInnerClassHelper" -- which is cool -- unfortunately, it doesn't compile. I'm happy to hand code this, but there must be a slick way of doing it that escapes me. As I said, I'm going to have a lot of them.

The code Tangible Software produces looks like this:

First it declares it with a using statement like this:

```
using OrientationEventListener = android.view.OrientationEventListener;
```

Then it creates this to handle the anonymous inner class:

```
private class OrientationEventListenerAnonymousInnerClassHelper : OrientationEventListener
{
    private readonly MainActivity outerInstance;

    public OrientationEventListenerAnonymousInnerClassHelper(MainActivity outerInstance, net.opencamera.MainActivity this) : base(this)
    {
        this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
    }

    public override void onOrientationChanged(int orientation)
    {
        outerInstance.onOrientationChanged(orientation);
    }
}
```

The Xamarin studio complains about the use of `net.opencamera.MainActivity this`, FWIW.

Since Java programmers love their anonymous inner classes, I'm going to have a lot of these to work through. What is the best practice for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An instance of an (anonymous) inner class in Java can only be created from within an instance of the outer class, and the inner instance contains a reference to the outer instance - thus, the structure of `OrientationEventListenerAnonymousInnerClassHelper` seems reasonable. However, the generator wasn't very smart to use `this` as a parameter name, since that's a reserved word in C# (as well as in Java). Rename it to anything else, and you should be good to go.

Edit: I guess changing large amounts of generated code will be impractical. The parameter name is probably derived from whatever is passed to the constructor of the anonymous inner class, so try this in your Java code, and then regenerate the C# code:

```
ContainingClassName self = this;
orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(self) { ... }
```

Comment: Aasmund (Don't know who downvoted your answer. Wish folks would say why...) Question tho: Whereas changing large amounts of generated code isn't fun, it seems to make more sense than changing large amounts of java source code first so it generates it right... doesn't it? Or what am I missing?

Comment: I can confirm that using 'this' as the parameter name was indeed a mistake - today's build of the converter will fix this.

Comment: The new build fixes this now.  Note that some people prefer to convert anonymous inner classes using delegates - the reason we don't do this is that it fails to handle more general complex cases.

Comment: @MarkJoel60: Me too... The answer to that depends on how much control you have over the source code, how simple the change is, and how many people will be affected by it - once, I did actually write a script to fix faulty generated code myself, so that may be a viable route. Luckily, it seems that the Xamarin people fixed the bug :-)

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Props for fast bugfixing!

Comment: I know... Amazing right! But to be specific, DaveDoknjas is from Tangible Software. Fastest bug fix I've ever seen I think. Makes me feel great about my investment there for sure.